# EF Core - Foreign key to the same table with custom column name with an overridden onDelete behaviour

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework-core, ef-fluent-api

I have one entity 'User' where the users can take multiple roles. So one such role is LineManager, and I track if any user is assigned LineManager by checking against the LineManagerId(which is the User's Id), here is the User entity:

```
public class User
{
    public Guid ID { get; set; }

    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("LineManager")]
    public Guid? LineManagerId { get; set; }

    public virtual User LineManager { get; set; }
}
```

The changes are applied and the foreign key is created fine in the database with the default migration generated. But here is my problem, when I override the default migration with the onDelete set to null as shown below (on the OnModelCreating method):

```
modelBuilder.Entity<User>().HasOne(u => u.LineManager)
.WithMany()
.HasForeignKey(e => e.LineManagerId)
.OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.SetNull);
```

I get the following error when applying migrations/updating database:

> Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_Users_Users_LineManagerId' on
>   table 'Users' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON
>   DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY
>   constraints. Could not create constraint or index. See previous errors

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Add `.WillCascadeOnDelete(false);` before `.OnDelete()`. let me know what happen !

Comment: Sorry I should have mentioned I'm using EF core.

Comment: Your relation is `one-to-one` self-referencing, WHY you are using `WithMany()`, I think you should replace it with `.WithOne(u => u.User)`